# formatting columns in java part 2

Tags: java, formatting

so i was able to align the first 2 columns but how do I get the other 3 columns to align as well???

this is my code :

```
  private static void makeFile(String[] name, String[] nickname, String[] capital, String[] flowers, String[] population) throws FileNotFoundException {
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter ("out.txt");
 for (int i = 0; i< 50 ; i++){
     out.printf("%-15s %s \n", name[i], nickname[i]+ " " +  capital[i] + " " +flowers[i]+ " "+ population[i]);

 }
 out.close();
}
```

}

this is what i get:
http://i1059.photobucket.com/albums/t424/dondon4720/statealignmentpart_zps38235d60.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your columns inside printf
something like

```
out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n", name[i], nickname[i], capital[i], flowers[i], population[i]);
```

you may need to adjust the -15 depending on the length of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
// Get the maximum length of any string in the array, or 0.
private static int getMaxLength(String[] in) {
  int c = 0;
  if (in != null && in.length > 0) {
    for (String i : in) {
      i = (i != null) ? i.trim() : "";
      if (i.length() > c) {
        c = i.length();
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}

// Pad any input string to the minimum length.
private static String padString(String in, int min) {
  in = (in != null) ? in.trim() : "";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in);
  while (sb.length() < min) {
    sb.append(' ');
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

private static void makeFile(String[] name,
  String[] nickname, String[] capital,
  String[] flowers, String[] population) {
  PrintWriter out = null;
  try {
    out = new PrintWriter("out.txt");

    // Add 1 to get at least 1 space between the maximum and the next item.
    int nameLen = getMaxLength(name) + 1;
    int nickLen = getMaxLength(nickname) + 1;
    int capitalLen = getMaxLength(capital) + 1;
    int flowersLen = getMaxLength(flowers) + 1;
    int populationLen = getMaxLength(population);

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
      out.println(padString(name[i], nameLen)
        + padString((nickname.length > i) ? nickname[i]
                : "", nickLen)
        + padString((capital.length > i) ? capital[i] : "",
            capitalLen)
        + padString((flowers.length > i) ? flowers[i] : "",
            flowersLen)
        + padString((population.length > i) ? population[i]
                : "", populationLen));
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace(System.err);
  } finally {
    out.close();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] name = { "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona" };
  String[] nickname = { "Yellowhammer State",
    "Last Frontier", "Grand Canyon State" }; 
  String[] capital = {
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "Y", "Z" };
  String[] flowers = { "Rose", "Carnation", "Orchid" };
  String[] population = { "1", "100", "1000" };
  makeFile(name, nickname, capital, flowers,
    population);
}
```